# Simple true/false statement about function composition

Tags: calculus, functions

Given the functions $f,g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is it true that

> If $f \circ g$ is strictly increasing and $f$ is injective then $g$
>   is monotonic

I believe this is false but I can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, you are right. You may consider the following $g,f$.

$g(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x & : x \in (-\infty ,0]\\
       x+1 & : x \in (0,1]\\
       1-\frac{1}{4} \exp\{-5x\} & :x\in(1,\infty)
     \end{array}
   \right.
$ $
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x & : x \in (-\infty ,0]\\
       x-1 & : x \in (1,2]\\
       x+5 &:x\in(0,1)\\
       x+100 &:x\in(2,\infty)
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

For 3, you should consider that $g$ is not strictly decreasing rather than $g$ is strictly increasing. It is not too hard to see if $g$ is not strictly decreasing, you would obtain a contradiction.

I think you reason 2,4 in a correct way.

Comment: I haven't learned about exponential function yet. Is there a simpler counterexample? Thank you.

Comment: I just want $g$ to be increasing on $(1,\infty)$ with range contained in $ (0,1)$, so maybe $1-\frac{1}{5+x}$.

Comment: but in your example $f(1)$ is undefined. $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and should be defined everywhere.

Comment: Right, I should make $f(x)=x+5$ on $(0,1]$. Your example surly works.

Comment: Thank you for your effort!